# How many worker processes should I allocate for an Application Pool in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-6, application-pools

I've got a Python application that I'm serving via IIS using [ISAPI-WSGI](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/).  I've got it in its own application pool so that I can restart the Python interpreter whenever I want without disturbing other applications.  I don't expect any more than 2 or 3 people to access it at any given time.  Is there any reason for me to change the max number of worker processes to greater than the default of 1?

Also, what criteria should I consider when deciding how many worker processes to allocate?  Is it just about concurrency or are there other factors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One worker process is enough in my opinion. Consider that requests are queued, not rejected, when another request is being served and no more threads are available in the process (I'm assuming that the process is multi-threaded).

Comment: Agreed.  2-3 people doesn't warrant any more workers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application hit.
By defaults **one Worker process for a application pool**.
If you increase the count of worker process more than one then it is called as *Web Garden* , for this You need to take care if there is in-proc session management.